# When the product of any two consecutive digits in the number is a prime number

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I came across a question today.

> The number of 10-digit numbers such that the product of any two consecutive digits in the number is a prime number, is?

As much as I know the product of any two consecutive digits is a prime number only when one of them is $1$ and the other is a prime number (unless I am missing something). But I still can't see any way forward. So, how to do this?

EDIT: The answer to this problem is

> 2048

Comment: I think you're off to a good start.  So basically, every other number has to be 1.  The other digits have to be 2,3,5, or 7.  Consider numbers of the form 1x1x1x1x1x, where x = 2,3,5, or 7.  Then, consider numbers of the form x1x1x1x1x1.   EDIT: I just realized that 1 is not a prime number, so the "x" here cannot be 1.

Comment: Is this good enough? 2121212121

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: x1x1x1x1x1, where x can be any of: 2,3, 5, 7

Comment: And the same with the x's and $1$s reversed.

Comment: the question is asking for the **number** of 10 digit numbers

Comment: Thought this would help you, but it did not! So here it is: $2^{11}$

Comment: but why is it $2^{11}$

Comment: For each x you have 4 possible selections (2, 3, 5, 7) - you multiply 4, 5 times ( for the 5 slots) - $4^5=2^{10}$. And than by 2 - see jorki comment.